# Spring Security method authorization not working

Tags: gwt, spring-security

here is the description of problem. I am develepping a web application with GWT. I have successfullly integrate spring security with gwt for the authentication feature with the following code. Now I want to use the spring "method security" in my web application. So I did what it says in http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html,

- just adding `<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>` in the above mentionned application context file.

  ```
   <http>
    <http-basic/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access=""/>

    <form-login />
    <logout />
   </http> 

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
          <user name="jimis" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
          <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    **<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>**
  ```
- then adding the annotation @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") above the function that I what to controle the access

Then I add the declaration of application context in the web.xml as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

 <!-- Default page to serve -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>App.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout> <!-- in minutes -->
  </session-config>
```

> ```
> <context-param>
>   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>   <param-value>
>       /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
>   </param-value>
>   </context-param>
>
>   <filter>
>     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
>   </filter>
>
>   <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>   </filter-mapping>
>
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
>   </listener>
> ```

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.app.example.server.AppServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>appService</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/app/appService.rpc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Note that I've just declared the gwt-servlet not the spring dispatcher servlet.

However it seems that this configuration doesn't work. In fact, whatever role can have the authority to access the function. 
Very Strange.
Hope your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `global-method-security` element containing both attributes.

Also read the [relevant section of the Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context) on issues with using method security and web controllers, if that's what you are doing (you will also find the same issue discussed here).

The log message you report is not an error and is unimportant unless you are using `hasPermission()` within your expressions.

Comment: Thanks, for the first commentary, I've done <!--<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled/> -->,

Comment: Thanks, for the first commentary, I've done <!--<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled/> -->, Then, the second commentary seems very interesting, I've just read the doc. I should give the backgroud,because I integrated spring security with GWT, in the web.xml, I declared gwt-servlet instead of dispatcherServlet; So if method-security should work with dispatherServlet, then the lack of declaration of DispatcherServlet results in this dis-function problem. So what is your idea?

Comment: I am sorry i havn't had the right to vote up for your answer, but it is really helpful

Comment: You should probably edit your question to give more information on where the bean instances you are trying to secure are defined and so on. Whether you are using GWT or whatever shouldn't be relevant. Method security can be used in non-web applications if desired.

Comment: I asked for information on where "the bean instances you are trying to secure are defined" - from your configuration it looks like you aren't securing Spring beans, so it won't work. If the objects you are trying to secure aren't manged by Spring, then Spring AOP (which method security relies on) won't have any effect. If this is the case, Spring Security will only work if you use aspectj.

Comment: You are right. After your remind I attempted to add the bean that I wanted to secure. Although then I met another problem descibed in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821683/how-to-correclty-integrate-gwt-sl-and-gilead-in-spring-beans-configuration, but now the problem is solved. Thanks very much for your help!